# Real Time Clock Issue with PIC18F87K22

Tags: pic

I'm working on a relatively simple board design using a PIC18F87K22 processor.  It spends most of its time asleep, waking up to send an alert via an embedded cell module when there's an external interrupt, or when triggered as a scheduled check-in by the real time clock.  It's using an external oscillator (CM200C32768DZFT) to drive the real time clock, and I'm noticing some occasional strange behavior.

Specifically, I'm noticing that the scheduled check-in is triggered much more frequently than expected, or sometimes much less frequently.  I'm sending the current clock status along with the cell packet, so that I can see that the device has apparently incremented by 60 minutes, even though much less time than that has passed.  It's not off by a consistent factor (and, as noted above, sometimes it can be fast or slow), and I have only seen it affecting some of the devices; others that are apparently identical appear to work fine.  Also, it's an issue that only appeared when we began testing outside in cold weather (the device is intended for outdoor operation).  Bringing one of the affected devices inside and letting it warm up does seem to resolve the problem.  However, we have not been able to replicate the problem indoors under controlled conditions, even in a freezer that reaches the same low temperatures that the device was exposed to outside.

So, a problem that only shows up sometimes, only for some devices and not others, and only under certain environmental conditions certainly seems to point to a hardware production problem.  But the failure rate is higher than I'd expect, and when we tried swapping out the oscillator on one of the affected boards from another that we knew was working, the problem stayed with the board, not the oscillator.  I'm attaching the relevant portion of the schematic and the board design itself.  Maybe there's something I'm doing wrong with the connection to the oscillator, maybe the oscillator itself should be replaced with a different component, maybe there's something obvious that I'm not thinking of in the circuit design that can cause an intermittent problem like this.  I'd be happy for any recommendations or suggestions.

[image: board_layout_x3]
[image: schematic_x3]

Edited to add:

Hmm, and maybe I'm looking in the wrong place for the source of the problem.  There is another oscillator on the board (FOXSDLF/160-20), tied to pins 49 and 50, maybe that's the primary clock input.  That one is tied to ground with 2 22pF capacitors.  I'll continue to do more research, but any additional comments or suggestions would be welcome.

[image: board_layout_x1]
[image: schematic_x1]

Edit to add further:

No, I think I was right the first time.  X1 is the primary oscillator, used for setting the main processor frequency when powered.  X3 is the secondary oscillator, used to drive the RTC even when the processor is asleep, and used to drive RTC-based interrupts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does microchip recommend that you connect the pencil lead crystal directly with no small capacitors to ground? You should check their data sheet and any app notes carefully.

Let me add that the Microchip MCU designs that I have done all have an external I<sup>2</sup>C RTC chip. The reason for this is that the RTC chips have a very convenient way to connect a small coil cell battery to one pin and another pin for the normal 3V3 VDD connection. Interface to the RTC is via a simple two wire interface which is in most cases already in use for other things as well so no extra GPIO loading for the RTC.

Trying to support a battery for the PIC MCU when it goes into sleep mode when the main power supply goes off adds the cost of extra components that can be eliminated when an external MCU is used. I have also found that the management of the RTC programming is less susceptible to upsets in the MCU software and so the current RTC readings can be more dependable.

To their credit Microchip has always done a great job of implementing low power sleep and idle modes on most of their MCUs. However I still wonder why we do not see a separate VBATT pin supported on their parts.

Comment: Worth looking into.  I'll see what I can dig up.  I inherited the board design, so I have not reviewed every possible detail.  Something like this that might have been overlooked is exactly what I'm hoping to find.

Comment: So, I'm able to find that Microchip recommends capacitors to ground on the primary oscillator, and the two 22pF caps there are in spec.  I've so far been unable to track down any specific recommendations for capacitors on a secondary oscillator either way for the the PIC18F87K22.  I'll continue to search.